# Get URLs and descriptions of Google search results in addition to titles

Tags: php, libcurl

I wrote this code – a Google search result parser – but it only gets titles:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=example&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

How can I also get URLs and descriptions?

Comment: What have you done to try and get the URLs/descriptions?

Comment: This code:  foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
  
  echo $link->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->value;
         
}   but I get a lot of links

Comment: google does not like be scraped, its against their TOS, and they actively try to stop you. to many attempts, and you will see a captcha or IP blocking

Comment: I know. I dont ask for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Link names and the url-s like so

Example:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=example&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue."\n";
    echo str_replace('/url?q=', '',$link->firstChild->getAttribute('href'))."\n";

    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: could you tell me how to get the description as well using your method above?